# Replace specific character within RegEx pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I replace specific characters that are within a RegEx pattern?

Let's say I have a string `git@github.com:foo-bar/baz`.

What I want to do is replace that colon with a `/` character.

```
var gitUrl = 'git@github.com:foo-bar/baz';
gitUrl.replace(/(github.com|bitbucket.org):/, '/'); // I want to keep github.com/bitbucket.org!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple `String.replace` with `String`, as Regex is not required.

```
gitUrl = gitUrl.replace(":", "/");
```

If you really want it, you would do use the captured group by `$1`

```
gitUrl = gitUrl.replace(/(github.com|bitbucket.org):/, "$1/");
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to replace all `:` though.

Comment: @Unidan even if my first code snippet was run, only the first colon will be replaced.